# Assigning empty object in class property?

Tags: php, class, syntax, properties

What is the proper way to assign a placeholder (empty object) to a class property?

Example:

```
class something {

    public $my_object = object; // ???

    public function __construct() {

        //create some object, via some function...

        $this->my_object = $some_object;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
class something {

    public $my_object;

    public function __construct() {

        $some_object = new StdClass();

        $this->my_object = $some_object;
    }

}
```

Test:

```
$obj = new something();
var_dump($obj);
```

Output:

```
object(something)#1 (1) {
  ["my_object"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought there may be a way to do upon being set, but this is fine too.